# Maven2 + native maven plugin

Tags: c, maven-2

My issue is pretty easy : I tried to compile an c standalone project for my companie. For that need, i installed the native maven plugin. In output,  i expect that the build generate 3 binaries files ( uexe )

But in the pom.xml i can only compile just a single file. Meaning the pom.xml can just handle one binary / or share lib... at a time.  ( in fact, i suspect this is a normal behavior due to the pom.xml format. The generated file is something like the artifactId + uexe as the extension, with no possibilities to change the output filename )

Do i need to create for each compiled file's from the native plugin a different pom.xml ? ( i think not ... )

Have you got some advices ? best pratices on how to handle that case ? 
Is there any way to compile at a time multiple binaries file with maven and the native plugin ? I heard something with nar ... but nar create nar archives that is not my need...

Thx a lot by advance !

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the plugin you used for compiling with multiple executions to produce multiple artifacts which should be distinct by the classifier for example.

```
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <executions>
           <execution>
             <goals>
               <goal>compile</goal>
             </goals>
             <phase>compile<phase>
             <configuration>
              ...
             </configuration>
           <execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a solution, but an observation. I am trying to use the plugin with multiple executions to build both a 32 and 64 bit DDL. In other to do that you need to have different "envFactoryName" to set up the the MS environment, which is put under the execution configuration.

However it seems to me that that the factory is only being done onces. So I am currently using a script instead.